# Jquery script not running in html-files included by angular

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have this very simple jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("h2").click(function(){
        alert("Hello world");
    })    
});
```

When I click on any h2 on the entire site, an alert will show up.

This works fine when I put an h2 anywhere in my index.html but when I put the h2 in some of the files included by angular, nothing happens when I click on the h2.

These are my files

```
index.htm
included.htm
myjqueryfunctions.js
```

Here is how I include the jquery-file

```
<body>
.... some code ....
<script src="jquery_functions.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is how I include the HTML-file using angular

```
<div ng-include src=" 'included.htm' "></div>
```

Everything else is working fine.

Question: Why does my jquery-script work fine when I put the h2 in my index.html but not when it is in the included.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you should call selector as below

```
 // This WILL work because we are listening on the 'document', 
    // for a click on an element with an tag h2
    $(document).on('click',"h2", function(){
            alert("Hello world");
        })  

    // This will NOT work because there is no 'h2' (added later or injected by angular)... yet
    $("h2").on("click",function() {
        alert("hello");
    });
```

Comment: CodeIsLife: Your answer did my day. It works perfect now! I salute you!! Thanks a lot!